# how to route from laravel.blade.php to other page depending on react router?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router-dom

I am using react with laravel.
to make my view routes depending on react router
I used this Route in web.php

```
Route::get('/{path?}',function(){return view('welcome');});
```

in addition to the other laravel routes

```
Route::post("history",[historyController::class,'store']);
...
```

react routes:

```
<Route exact path="/history" render={  
                    ()=>auth?  
                    <React.Fragment>  
                    <NavbarComp />  
                    <Container>  
                        <History/>  
                    </Container>  
                    </React.Fragment>  
                    :
                    <Redirect to={{pathname:'/login'}}/>
                }/>
```

I also have laravel mail.blade.php

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' =>""]) shopping
 history   
@endcomponent
```

so the question is how to route from this mail.blade.php to /history page in react route above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just use the helper function [url](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url)
like that:

```php
@component('mail::button', ['url' =>url('history')]) shopping
 history   
@endcomponent
```